# Symfony2 -one insert but multiple new duplicated rows

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem with inserting row to db.

My code:

```
    $offer = new Offers();
    $offer->setOffer($url);
    $offer->setPage('3');
    $this->em->persist($offer); 
    $this->em->flush(); 
    exit('TEST');
```

When I execute my code, in db appears not 1 but 3 new rows.
I added exit() on the end of my code to by sure that code is executed only once.
What can by the cause of this problem?

Comment: Checks if there are any related listener on "PostPersist", "Flush", etc. Doctrine events ?

Comment: No one listeners, other functions in my project work properly.

Comment: I used XDebug and my project is executed 3 times. I don't know why. ;/

Comment: MySQL ? SQLServer ?

Comment: How and where is this code being called?

Comment: Can you post your Offers-Class ?

Comment: I use MySQL. I don't know how it work, but when debugger reaches to line with end(), automatically started from the first line of Symfony framework.

Comment: @Florian Offer-class is too long, but is completely normal class without any post-Inserting functions

Comment: Do you call the given piece of code inside you Offers Class ? Can you provide more of the class surounding the code ?